# My route returns a blank view (no html when I do view source)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am ***brand new*** to Ruby on Rails and I have been trying to get a simple default route set up and working. When I try to run my application I get a blank result (if I do a view source, there is nothing there).

Here are the relevant files (not sure if I am missing something that would be useful).

### app/config/routes.rb

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => "home#index"
end
```

### app/views/home/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Home#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/home/index.html.erb</p>
```

### app/controllers/home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

### app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Benji</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

When I try to run my application, I go to http://localhost:3000 and nothing shows up. If I do a view source, it is empty.

If do `rake routes` this is the result:

```
JESSE-GAVINs-MacBook-Pro-17:benji jesse$ rake routes
(in /Users/jesse/Dev/benji)
root  /(.:format) {:action=>"index", :controller=>"home"}
JESSE-GAVINs-MacBook-Pro-17:benji jesse$
```

In my development.log file I see this:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Sep 07 10:44:10 -0500 2010
  Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (2.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 15ms (Views: 14.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

What could be the issue? How do I go about solving this?

Comment: Please post the contents of `app/views/home/index.html.erb`.

Comment: I presume you mean that you edited `config/routes.rb` rather than `config.ru`?

Comment: @jdl the code has been appended to my question. and @John Topley, YES, I did mean config/routes.rb. I have updated that in my question too. Thanks for your clarification.

Comment: Have you some trace on your log file ?

Comment: What response do you get if you do `curl http://localhost:3000` in a Terminal window?

Comment: @shingara. I have appended my question with log info.  @John Topley, when I do a curl on that url it doesn't do anything, just shows another prompt.

Comment: Next up to check would be your layout file. Can you post that please?

Comment: @jdl I have posted the layout file (and cleaned up the question a bit). Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: @klew. I have added the controller code. I am so new to this I am not even really sure what you all need in order to get a picture of the app.

Comment: It looks good. Try adding `render :text => "Hello everybody!"` to index method in controller. It should render only this string and it should be visible in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solved (sort of...)

It works just fine when I started the rails server on a different port.

It was my understanding that I didn't need to restart the server in order for it to detect changes in the code.

Sorry about the waste of time, I just didn't know which tree I needed to bark up. I learned some things along the way.

Comment: When you are working in development mode, in most cases you don't need to restart your server.

Answer (score 0):

As you're playing with Routes, you absolutely need to restart the server. I don't know if this is part of the problem, but most (all?) things under config/ need the server to be restarted to take effect, particularly routes and environment

Comment: You don't need to restart server after changing routes

Comment: Really? Interesting. I thought everything under config needed a restart. I know if you're using RESTful routes, you can create a new action and it'll automatically get translated into a route, but I didn't know you can map a new route without restarting. Good to know