# routes lead to blank view, no html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, view

I have a very similar issue to this question: [My route returns a blank view (no html when I do view source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659445/my-route-returns-a-blank-view-no-html-when-i-do-view-source)

When I access a route, it just shows a blank view with no html when viewing source.

[My route returns a blank view (no html when I do view source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659445/my-route-returns-a-blank-view-no-html-when-i-do-view-source)

`config/routes.rb`

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  root to: 'home#index'
end
```

`app/controllers/home_controller.rb`

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end
end
```

`app/views/home/index.html.slim` (slim is like erb, I tested both out but still no html rendered)

```
h1 get ready to party!
```

`log/development.log`

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-05 00:36:21 -0500
Processing by HomeController#index as */*
  Rendered home/index.html.slim within layouts/application (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 5.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

The other question suggested changing ports. I did all the basic stuff like restart server, restart computer, try different ports.

Comment: Do you have a blank index.html file in your public/ directory?

Comment: If he did, then we wouldn't get render messages in the log.

Comment: I solved it. Someone added a basically blank application.html.erb file with no `yield`, so the application.html.slim wasn't getting loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your layout could be blank and is not rendering the index view.

The default layout is `application.html.erb` and should render your views with `<%= yield %>`.

Also - have you tried restarting your server for kicks?  That's the answer to the other SO question you posted so I'm assuming you've tried that...

Comment: Ah. I have both an `application.html.erb` and `application.html.slim`. The `application.html.slim` file has the `<%= yield %>` and it doesn't seem to be getting called.